# Google Checkout Account Username

Tags: android, google-checkout

I'm looking for a method that returns me the Google Checkout User Account of the owner of the telephone...

I explain: when I buy an application over the market, in the phone is stored somewhere the Google Account that I use to purchase the app (that maybe can be different from the main google main account?). I need a method, if exists, that gives me this account (only the username, I don't need the password!).

Thanx in advance

Comment: No we won't help you hack google checkout accounts.

Comment: I need only the username, not the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

googleCheckoutUser = accounts[0].name.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can retrieve that information, since I would consider it to be private data.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist.  The notion of what Google account is used for Market login assumes the device has a Market application, and that's not guaranteed.

An application wanting access to another's private data must be signed with the same key and the applications must have made provisions to share a UID.  [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidsecurity/index.html) has a nice overview of how all of this works.